# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Tags: apex, trigger, permissions, sharing

I have been battling with this for few days now. Below is my scenario. 
I do have a trigger on Sampling__c object that updates the owner and assigns a manager for the request created. When updating the bu manager, I am receiving the following error :INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY 
 
Below is the line that I am trying to update from debug log.

> 15:16:427.410 (2410228087)|USER_DEBUG|[136]|DEBUG|CodeDebugging::
>   lstSampleUpdate = (Sampling__c:{Id=a0cc0000006UnrhAAC,
>   BU_manager__c=005E0000000ReHdIAK, BU_manager1__c=005E0000001dtsCIAQ,
>   BU_manager2__c=005E0000000ReHdIAK, BU_manager3__c=005E0000000ReHdIAK,
>   BU_manager4__c=005E0000000ReHdIAK}) 
> 15:16:427.410
>   (2410233311)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[136]|System.debug(ANY)
>   
> 15:16:427.410
>   (2410281089)|DML_BEGIN|[137]|Op:Update|Type:Sampling__c|Rows:1
>   15:16:427.433 (2433914293)|DML_END|[137] 
> 15:16:427.434
>   (2434036718)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[137]|System.DmlException: Update
>   failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0cc0000006UnrhAAC; first
>   error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient
>   access rights on cross-reference id: [] 
> 15:16:427.438
>   (2438620518)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[141]|String.valueOf(Object)
>   
> 15:16:427.438
>   (2438657509)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[141]|String.valueOf(Object)
>   
> 15:16:427.438
>   (2438679644)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[141]|System.debug(ANY)
>   
> 15:16:427.438 (2438689496)|USER_DEBUG|[141]|DEBUG|Exception : Not
>   able to update the BU Manager System.DmlException: Update failed.
>   First exception on row 0 with id a0cc0000006UnrhAAC; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id: [] 
> 15:16:427.438
>   (2438696016)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[141]|System.debug(ANY)

```
    public static void populateBUManagerOnSample(List<Sampling__c>sampling)
{
//After insert Trigger
List<Business_Unit_Managers__c> lstBUMgrs=[Select b.Product_Line__c ,b.Product_Family__c,b.Object_Type__c, b.Item_Accounting_Class__c, b.Id, b.Business_Unit__c, b.BU_Manager__c, b.BU_Manager1__c, b.BU_Manager2__c, b.BU_Manager3__c, b.BU_Manager4__c From Business_Unit_Managers__c b where b.Object_Type__c='Sample'];

System.Debug('CodeDebugging::');
Map<String, > MapBUMgrs = new Map<String,Business_Unit_Managers__c>();
List<Sampling__c > lstSampleUpdate=new List<Sampling__c >();

for(Business_Unit_Managers__c bu:lstBUMgrs) {
MapBUMgrs.put(bu.Item_Accounting_Class__c + bu.Product_Line__c + bu.Product_Family__c ,bu);
System.Debug('CodeDebugging:: Map BU ' + bu.Item_Accounting_Class__c  + ' == ' + bu.Product_Line__c + ' == ' + bu.Product_Family__c);
  }

 if(Trigger.isAfter){
 for(Sampling__c sp: sampling){  
 id tempUser;
 Sampling__c s = new Sampling__c (id=sp.id); 
 System.Debug('CodeDebugging:: Compare=' + sp.Business_Unit__c + ' == ' + sp.Product_Line__c + ' == ' + sp.Product_Family__c);

if(MapBUMgrs.containsKey(sp.Business_Unit__c+ sp.Product_Line__c + sp.Product_Family__c )){
Business_Unit_Managers__c temps = MapBUMgrs.get(sp.Business_Unit__c+ sp.Product_Line__c + sp.Product_Family__c);
System.Debug('CodeDebugging:: Inside BU');
System.Debug('CodeDebugging:: BU manager' + temps.BU_Manager__c);
                                if(temps.BU_Manager__c!=null)
                                tempUser = temps.BU_Manager__c;
                                else if(temps.BU_Manager1__c!=null)
                                tempUser=temps.BU_Manager__c;
                                else if(temps.BU_Manager2__c!=null)
                                tempUser=temps.BU_Manager__c;
                                else if(temps.BU_Manager3__c!=null)
                                tempUser=temps.BU_Manager__c;
                                else if(temps.BU_Manager4__c!=null)
                                tempUser=temps.BU_Manager__c;
                                s.BU_Manager__c  =(temps.BU_Manager__c!=null  ? temps.BU_Manager__c :tempUser);
                                s.BU_Manager1__c =(temps.BU_Manager1__c!=null ? temps.BU_Manager1__c :tempUser);
                                s.BU_Manager2__c =(temps.BU_Manager2__c!=null ? temps.BU_Manager2__c :tempUser);
                                s.BU_Manager3__c =(temps.BU_Manager3__c!=null ? temps.BU_Manager3__c :tempUser);
                                s.BU_Manager4__c =(temps.BU_Manager4__c!=null ? temps.BU_Manager4__c :tempUser);
                                System.Debug('CodeDebugging:: UpdateSample = ' + s);
                                lstSampleUpdate.add(s);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    try{
                        System.Debug('CodeDebugging:: lstSampleUpdate = ' + lstSampleUpdate);
                        update lstSampleUpdate;
                        System.Debug('Product Line! ' + lstSampleUpdate);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.Debug('Exception : Not able to update the BU Manager ' + e);
                    }
                }
```

I checked the permission for the new user assigned and the request creator and they both have create/edit/read permission on the object. I checked the Sampling__Share object and there is an entry for the new record created too.

Any idea what else to search for? Any input greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this object have a record type ? Business_Unit_Managers__c, also read this post ; http://www.forcetree.com/2011/12/insufficientaccessoncrossreferenceentit.html and see if there is a relevant scenario for your case

Comment: Hi Rao, I did test these scenario's already and don't see anything related to that.

Comment: are you getting this exception on certain users or on all the users at random inervals? Can you login as one of the user and see if the can access this specific 'a0cc0000006UnrhAAC' record of the Sampling__c object.

Comment: You may want to execute this functionality after giving Modify All" rights to the concerned user, just to make sure some profile/FLS issues .

Comment: I am not getting this error for all the user. Just for some external users who try  to create the request. After creating, the request, when the apex class tries to update the manager field, this error happens.  When I try to access the 'a0cc0000006UnrhAAC' as the user who creates it, they are able to see the record. But they do not have edit previlage. Maybe this might be the issue. How can I resolve it.

Comment: Hi Dev, Can you please explain the solution? Do you mean to run the sharing method after doing all the operations of updates?

Comment: Are your external users portal users, if they are what is their profile in SFDC?

Comment: Yes.. I am trying to create record using External portal user and then the issue happens. The profile is custom that is created for company with privileges.

Comment: have you provided read/ write access to this profile for Sampling object?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24739/portal-user

Comment: For external user's I am not able to give read/write previlage. When I try to do that it shows the following error  "Error: Unable to change sharing model because sharing objects are referenced by the following components:"

Comment: get on the chat room  
chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24739/portal-user

Comment: Sorry Rao.. I don't have enough reputation to activate the chat.

Comment: Check this out : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XnvAAE the steps described here may help you out

Answer (score 0):

insufficient access rights on cross-reference id mean that some of the field of your a0cc0000006UnrhAAC record is out of your authorization check the field(s), especially the filed that look up to the others records if you have access or not.